# Track down PHP error "Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in Unknown on line 1 at Unknown#0"

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, php-5.4, owncloud, raspberry-pi2

I've just set up a RPi 2 with the latest stable Raspbian and installed some basic stuff (nginx, php5, ownCloud 8, SickBeard, sabnzbd+, ...).

The ownCloud log shows a pretty generic error message at every page load and sometimes in between: `Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in Unknown on line 1 at Unknown#0`

I do understand the meaning of the error message but I have no idea on how to track down the file which is responsible for it since it's not named in the error message.

I've already checked all ini files within `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d` since I stumbled across that directory on various Google searches but none of the files inside has a line starting with '#'.

I'd really appreciate any help since I'd really like to keep the log clean so that real issues could be located/recognized more easily...

Thanks & best regards

Comment: This is not an _error_, but a _warning_. Most likely this refers to your owncloud config file at `.....owncloud/config/config.php`...

Answer (score 0):

```
find /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/ -name "*.ini" -exec sed -i -re 's/^(\s*)#(.*)/\1;\2/g' {} \;
```

This will find all comments starting from # and replace ;